# Messed up UI after Manjaro xfce reinstall

Tags: xfce, manjaro, gui, theme

So.. I had the Arc Dark theme on my Manjaro xfce and I had to reinstall the OS. After that I installed the Arc theme again but now some windows look different and their theme doesn't change regardless of which theme I set. As you can see in the image below, the Manjaro Settings Manager window looks quite different compared to the File Manager window. Does anybody now what the problem might be?

[image: Desktop Screenshot]

Comment: You are probably looking for [Kvantum Manager](https://github.com/tsujan/Kvantum/blob/master/Kvantum/README.md), to set Arc theme for your Qt applications as well.

Comment: Yup. That was it. Thank you sir!